# Group by list of keys (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, grouping

Assume I have a

```
class Question(val tags:List<String>, val text:String)
```

which (obviously) has multiple tags in addition to other attributes.

I want to convert a number of Question instances to a (single!) tag to Question map such as: `Map<String,List<Question>>`.

How do I do that? A simple `groupBy { it.tags }` provides a `Map<List<String>,List<Question>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic extension function for this, as I've required it a few times:

```
fun <T, K> Iterable<T>.groupByMany(
    keyExtractor: (T) -> Iterable<K>
): Map<K, List<T>> = mutableMapOf<K, MutableList<T>>()
    .also { grouping ->
        forEach { item ->
            keyExtractor(item).forEach { key ->
                grouping.computeIfAbsent(key) { mutableListOf() }.add(item)
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
val byTag = questions.groupByMany { it.tags }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val questions: Iterable<Question> = ....
val map = HashMap<String, MutableList<Question>>()
questions.forEach { question ->
    question.tags.forEach { tag ->
        val otherQuestions = map[tag]
        if (otherQuestions == null) map[tag] = arrayListOf(question)
        else otherQuestions.add(question)
    }
}
val resultMap: Map<String, List<Question>> = map
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that works (can be simplified though, e.g. computeIfAbsent), but I was rather wondering if the Kotlin grouping support can be used for this